# Bash script echo seems to remove my new lines?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, echo

This is the contents of my file file.txt:

```
header
a
b
c
```

I have no idea what is going on. This command does not print new lines.

```
echo -e $(tail -n +2 file.txt)
```

This prints:

```
a b c
```

But if you write it to file you will clearly see new lines:

```
tail -n +2 file.txt >> new_file.txt
```

test.txt

```
a
b
c
```

How do I force echo to print the new lines? I don't think I can use `printf` here without making some kind of loop.

Comment: Why are you using `echo` here. Just use `tail -n +2 file`

Comment: If you have to use `echo` then quote it: `echo "$(tail -n +2 file)"` or `printf "%s\n" "$(tail -n +2 file)"`

Comment: Oh right, I am still learning bash script and was told echo is for printing stuff. But is there a reason why echo doesn't print the new lines?

Comment: `echo` doesn't see them. The shell is removing them, because you used `$(...)` without the quotes.

Comment: BTW, the `-e` argument to `echo` is nonstandard (in fact, any `echo` which does anything but print `-e` on output when given that argument on input is *breaking* [the relevant standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), which only allows `-n` to be processed as an option). If you want to process escape sequences, the compliant way is with `printf '%b\n' "your string"`. Even in bash, the noncompliant way can fail if both `posix` and `xpg_echo` flags are set.

Comment: Related: [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)

Answer (score 5):

Echo statement within quotes give your output with newline terminated lines. Here is the code

```
echo -e "$(tail -n +2 file.txt)"
```

Comment: Why would one do that, instead of just `tail -n +2 file.txt`, with no `echo` present at all?